# How to Evaluate this Integral of a Green's Function

Tags: integration, contour-integration

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ be given. I have the following integral:
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i k n}}{2\left[1-\cos\left(k\right)\right]-z}dk$$which I am not sure how to solve, because the boundaries of integration are not infinite, so I'm not sure how contour integration and residues would lend themselves to this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I(z)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ikn}}{2(1-\cos(k))-z}\,dk$.

Enforcing the substitution $w=e^{ik}$ so that $dk=\frac{1}{iw}\,dw$, $I(z)$ can be written

$$I(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|w|=1} \frac{w^n}{-w^2+(2-z)w-1}\,dw \tag 1$$

The integral in $(1)$ can be evaluated using the residue theorem.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased that this helped.